# Scrapy multiple search terms

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am very new to Python and I am in the process of learning on how scrape web pages (1 day in). The task I want to achieve is to loop through a list of 2000 companies and extract revenue data and the number of employees. I started by using scrapy, and I have managed to get the workflow to work for one company (not elegant, but at least I am trying)- but I cannot figure out how I can load the list of companies and loop through to carry out multiple searches. I have a feeling this is a fairly simple procedure.

So, my main question is - where in the spider class should I define the query array of companies to loop through? I do not know the exact URLs since each company has a unique ID and belongs to specific market - so I can not input them as start_urls.
Is Scrapy the right tool or should I have used mechanize - for this type of task?

Here is my current code.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.http import Request
from tutorial.items import DmozItem
import json

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["proff.se"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.proff.se"]

# Search on the website, currently I have just put in a static search term here, but I would like to loop over a list of companies.

    def parse(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'q': rebtel},callback=self.search_result)

# I fetch the url from the search result and convert it to correct Financial-url where the information is located.

    def search_result(self,response):
        sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        link = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="company-list two-columns"]/li/a/@href').extract()
        finance_url=str(link[0]).replace("/foretag","http://www.proff.se/nyckeltal")
        return Request(finance_url,callback=self.parse_finance)

# I Scraped the information of this particular company, this is hardcoded and will not 
# work for other responses. I had some issues with the encoding characters
# initially since they were Swedish. I also tried to target the Json element direct by
# revenue = sel.xpath('#//*[@id="accountTable1"]/tbody/tr[3]/@data-chart').extract()
# but was not able to parse it (error - expected string or buffer - tried to convert it
# to a string by str() with no luck, something off with the formatting, which is messing the the data types.    

    def parse_finance(self, response):
        sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        datachart = sel.xpath('//tr/@data-chart').extract()
        employees=json.loads(datachart[36])
        revenue = json.loads(datachart[0])
        items = []
        item = DmozItem()
        item['company']=response.url.split("/")[-5]
        item['market']=response.url.split("/")[-3]
        item['employees']=employees
        item['revenue']=revenue
        items.append(item)
        return item
```

Answer (score 2):

The common approach is to do this with a command-line argument. Give the spider's `__init__` method an argument:

```
class ProffSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "proff"
    ...

    def __init__(self, query):
        self.query = query

    def parse(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formdata={'q': self.query},
            callback=self.search_result
        )

    ...
```

And then start your spiders (maybe with Scrapyd):

```
$ scrapy crawl proff -a query="something"
$ scrapy crawl proff -a query="something else"
```

If you want to run a bunch of spiders at once by passing in the arguments from a file, you can create a new command to run multiple instances of a spider. This is just mixing the builtin `crawl` command with the [example code for running multiple spiders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process) with a single crawler:

**`your_project/settings.py`**

```
COMMANDS_MODULE = 'your_project_module.commands'
```

**`your_project/commands/__init__.py`**

```
# empty file
```

**`your_project/commands/crawl_many.py`**

```
import os
import csv

from scrapy.commands import ScrapyCommand
from scrapy.utils.python import without_none_values
from scrapy.exceptions import UsageError


class Command(ScrapyCommand):
    requires_project = True

    def syntax(self):
        return '[options]'

    def short_desc(self):
        return 'Run many instances of a spider'

    def add_options(self, parser):
        ScrapyCommand.add_options(self, parser)

        parser.add_option('-f', '--input-file', metavar='FILE', help='CSV file to load arguments from')
        parser.add_option('-o', '--output', metavar='FILE', help='dump scraped items into FILE (use - for stdout)')
        parser.add_option('-t', '--output-format', metavar='FORMAT', help='format to use for dumping items with -o')

    def process_options(self, args, opts):
        ScrapyCommand.process_options(self, args, opts)

        if not opts.output:
            return

        if opts.output == '-':
            self.settings.set('FEED_URI', 'stdout:', priority='cmdline')
        else:
            self.settings.set('FEED_URI', opts.output, priority='cmdline')

        feed_exporters = without_none_values(self.settings.getwithbase('FEED_EXPORTERS'))
        valid_output_formats = feed_exporters.keys()

        if not opts.output_format:
            opts.output_format = os.path.splitext(opts.output)[1].replace('.', '')

        if opts.output_format not in valid_output_formats:
            raise UsageError('Unrecognized output format "%s". Valid formats are: %s' % (opts.output_format, tuple(valid_output_formats)))

        self.settings.set('FEED_FORMAT', opts.output_format, priority='cmdline')

    def run(self, args, opts):
        if args:
            raise UsageError()

        with open(opts.input_file, 'rb') as handle:
            for spider_options in csv.DictReader(handle):
                spider = spider_options.pop('spider')
                self.crawler_process.crawl(spider, **spider_options)

        self.crawler_process.start()
```

You can run it like so:

```
$ scrapy crawl_many -f crawl_options.csv -o output_file.jsonl
```

The format of the crawl options CSV is simple:

```
spider,query,arg2,arg3
proff,query1,value2,value3
proff,query2,foo,bar
proff,query3,baz,asd
```

Comment: But can this approach take a list of elements ?

Comment: But can this approach take a list of elements? scrapy crawl dmoz -a query="companies.txt" will be a list of companies.                              def _init_(self,query):                                         companies = [line.strip() for line in open(query)]
self.query = companies, Maybe I am not really following what you are suggesting.

Comment: I figured it out - actually the start URL for the search query is http://www.proff.se/bransch-s%C3%B6k?q="Company name" - hence I can just merge a file with all the names and then read it in as start_urls, or even do the _Init_ if I want to use different file sets. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @johndoe: Do what, exactly?

Comment: @Blender  show a) how to pass a list of terms (e.g. a .csv column, a .txt file, or a list of strings) to a search box element, b) return into a directory each indexed site as an html file, and c) crawl into a csv specific items/elements of the site.

Comment: @johndoe: (b) is out of the scope of this question, but see my edit for the other parts.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Blender. However, it would be more helpful for others to have a toy reproducible example of this case. Could you provide a real case of how to do `a)` and `c)`. For instance, OP's site.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Blender. However, it would be more helpful for others to have a toy reproducible example of this case. Could you provide a real case of how to do a) and c). For instance, OP's site. I read the edit and although it shows how to do it, it can not be runned..

Comment: @tumbleweed: The `crawl_many` command is independent of your spiders, so I'm not sure how that would help. Take the example project off of the Scrapy documentation and create the `commands/crawl_many.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is to create a list of companies and find a way to get the url of each one. After this crawling is easy. I have written a crawler to extract disease information from wikipedia from a list of diseases. See how it fits your use case.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import pandas as pd
from subprocess import Popen, check_call
from multiprocessing import Pool
#nltk.download()

def crawlwiki(keywords):
    print (keywords)
    columns = ['Category', 'Text']
    page=1
    print ('Fetching for {}....'.format(keywords))
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'
    for i in range(len(keywords)):
        url = url + keywords[i]
        url = url + '%20'

    url = url[0:(len(url)-3)]   
    output_obj = {}
    #curr_page = url+str(page)
    while True:
        try:
            page_source = requests.get(url)
        except:

#What you should do if internet connection fails
        break

    plain_text = page_source.text
    bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")
    '''toc_links = bs_obj.findAll('div', {'class': 'toc-links'})
    base_url = 'http://www.webmd.com'
    for div in toc_links:
        links = div.findAll('a')
        for a in links:
            output_obj[a.text] = base_url + a.get('href')
            print (base_url + a.get('href'))
    data = bs_obj.findAll('div', {'class':'search-text-container'})
    for div in data:
        links = div.findAll('a')
        for a in links:
            output_obj[a.text] = a.get('href')
            print (a.get('href'))'''


    """
        Mapping:
        1 : Signs and symptoms
        2 : Diagnosis
        3 : Prognosis
        4 : Treatment

    """

    symptom_text = re.findall ( '<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="Signs_and_symptoms">Signs and symptoms</span>(.*?)<h2>', plain_text, re.DOTALL)
    str1 = ''.join(symptom_text)
    symptoms_object = BeautifulSoup(str1, "lxml")
    #paragraphs = re.findall('<p>(.*?)<p>', str1, re.DOTALL)
    symptom_data = symptoms_object.findAll('p')
    symptom_paragraphs = ""
    for p in symptom_data:
        symptom_paragraphs += p.text

    symptom_paragraphs = re.sub(r"/?\[\d+]" , '', symptom_paragraphs, re.DOTALL)
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['1', symptom_paragraphs]], columns=columns)

    diagnosis_text = re.findall ( '<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="Diagnosis">Diagnosis</span>(.*?)<h2>', plain_text, re.DOTALL)
    str1 = ''.join(diagnosis_text)
    diagnosis_object = BeautifulSoup(str1, "lxml")
    #paragraphs = re.findall('<p>(.*?)<p>', str1, re.DOTALL)
    diagnosis_data = diagnosis_object.findAll('p')
    diagnosis_paragraphs = ""
    for p in diagnosis_data:
        diagnosis_paragraphs += p.text

    diagnosis_paragraphs = re.sub(r"/?\[\d+]"   , '', diagnosis_paragraphs, re.DOTALL)
    df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['2', diagnosis_paragraphs]], columns=columns)

    prognosis_text = re.findall ( '<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="Prognosis">Prognosis</span>(.*?)<h2>', plain_text, re.DOTALL)
    str1 = ''.join(prognosis_text)
    prognosis_object = BeautifulSoup(str1, "lxml")
    #paragraphs = re.findall('<p>(.*?)<p>', str1, re.DOTALL)
    prognosis_data = prognosis_object.findAll('p')
    prognosis_paragraphs = ""
    for p in prognosis_data:
        prognosis_paragraphs += p.text

    prognosis_paragraphs = re.sub(r"/?\[\d+]"   , '', prognosis_paragraphs, re.DOTALL)
    df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['3', prognosis_paragraphs]], columns=columns)

    treatment_text = re.findall ( '<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="Treatment">Treatment</span>(.*?)<h2>', plain_text, re.DOTALL)
    str1 = ''.join(treatment_text)
    treatment_object = BeautifulSoup(str1, "lxml")
    #paragraphs = re.findall('<p>(.*?)<p>', str1, re.DOTALL)
    treatment_data = treatment_object.findAll('p')
    treatment_paragraphs = ""
    for p in treatment_data:
        treatment_paragraphs += p.text

    treatment_paragraphs = re.sub(r"/?\[\d+]"   , '', treatment_paragraphs, re.DOTALL)
    df_4 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['4', treatment_paragraphs]], columns=columns)

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)

    df = df.append(df_1.append(df_2.append(df_3.append(df_4))))

    return df
    print('Fetch completed....')



def main():

    disease_df = pd.read_csv("disease.txt", sep="\n", header=None)

    columns = ['Category', 'Text']
    df_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
    size = disease_df.size
    print("Initializing....")
    p = Pool(5)
    df_data = p.map(crawlwiki, disease_df.values.tolist())
    """for index, row in disease_df.iterrows():
        print('Iteration {0} out of {1}.....'.format(index+1, size))
        df = crawlwiki(row, columns)
        df_data = df_data.append(df)"""

    df_data.to_csv("TagDataset.csv", index=False)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Nice crawling.. let me check it

Comment: This question is specifically tagged `scrapy` and this answer isn't really useful for someone using scrapy.

Comment: @Blender The question did not focus on what package you use for crawling, it wanted a method to crawl a list of search terms and that is what is highlighted here. Not the crawling itself.